# Pandas: Create column in dataframe based on if-else statement and with values from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes A and B like so:

```
A:

+----+-------+--------+-----+
| ID | Round | Column | row |
+----+-------+--------+-----+
|  1 | A     |      1 |   1 |
|  1 | A     |      2 |   1 |
|  1 | A     |      3 |   1 |
|  1 | A     |      4 |   1 |
|  1 | A     |      5 |   1 |
|  1 | A     |      6 |   1 |
|  1 | A     |      1 |   2 |
|  1 | A     |      2 |   2 |
|  1 | A     |      3 |   2 |
|  1 | A     |      4 |   2 |
|  1 | A     |      5 |   2 |
|  1 | A     |      6 |   2 |
+----+-------+--------+-----+


B:
+-----+-----------------------------+
| ID  |         Categories          |
+-----+-----------------------------+
|   1 | [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m] |
|   2 | [n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z] |
| ... | ...                         |
+-----+-----------------------------+
```

edit2: Each row is dataframe a is a Jeopardy question, and every row in dataframe B is a game.

There are 3 rounds, 6 columns, and 5 rows, and like 3000 IDs.

I'm trying to create a new column in A that looks like this:

```
+----+-------+--------+-----+----------+
| ID | Round | Column | row | Category |
+----+-------+--------+-----+----------+
|  1 | A     |      1 |   1 | a        |
|  1 | A     |      2 |   1 | b        |
|  1 | A     |      3 |   1 | c        |
|  1 | A     |      4 |   1 | d        |
|  1 | A     |      5 |   1 | e        |
|  1 | A     |      6 |   1 | f        |
|  1 | A     |      1 |   2 | a        |
|  1 | A     |      2 |   2 | b        |
|  1 | A     |      3 |   2 | c        |
|  1 | A     |      4 |   2 | d        |
|  1 | A     |      5 |   2 | e        |
|  1 | A     |      6 |   2 | f        |
+----+-------+--------+-----+----------+
```

I'm pretty lost on how to actually do this. I thought about using np.select(conditions, values), where there are 13 conditions. I think this would work decently if there were only one id, but not I'm not sure how to scale it upwards. Additionally I think splitting the categories in B into 13 columns could be useful, but I'm not sure what the next step would be.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

edit: The conditions are as follows, though I'm not sure how to incorporate ID and the values from dataframe 2

```
conditions = [
    ((df['round'] == 'A') & (df['column'] == 1)),
    ((df['round'] == 'A') & (df['column'] == 2)),
    ((df['round'] == 'A') & (df['column'] == 3)),
    ((df['round'] == 'A') & (df['column'] == 4)),
    ((df['round'] == 'A') & (df['column'] == 5)),
    ((df['round'] == 'A') & (df['column'] == 6)),
    ((df['round'] == 'B') & (df['column'] == 1)),
    ((df['round'] == 'B') & (df['column'] == 2)),
    ((df['round'] == 'B') & (df['column'] == 3)),    
    ((df['round'] == 'B') & (df['column'] == 4)),
    ((df['round'] == 'B') & (df['column'] == 5)),    
    ((df['round'] == 'B') & (df['column'] == 6)),
    (df['round'] == 'C')
    ]
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic of matching. Why does it repeat for row 1 and 2?

Comment: Your Categories from df_b are mapped to your ID and Column in df_a?

Comment: @Erfan It's data from Jeopardy, so the matching works like [this](https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/19577016/jeopardy_02.jpg)

Comment: @ScottBoston Yes, I just edited the post with more specific details on the mapping if that helps

Comment: Can you explain the logic of matching, why a,b,c,d,e,f only are repeating?

Comment: Doesit need to match on 1st 6 entries from the Category list ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m'] ?

Comment: @AnupTiwari Each row is A is a jeopardy question, and each row in B is all the categories in a single game. Each round has its own table, like [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/51/Jeopardy%21_game_board_US.svg/1920px-Jeopardy%21_game_board_US.svg.png). So every row in round A column 1 in df_A corresponds to 'a' in df_B, every row in column 2 corresponds to 'b' in df_b. Then for double jeopardy every row in column 1 corresponds to 'g'